# CommandButton with JavaScript and controller method

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component, commandbutton

I have a page with apex:commandButton which calls javascript to validate image selected and a method from controller to upload image. For some reason before javascript is done executing, controller method is called and if a huge image is selected I can view state error

> Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded

Here is my code. Is there a workaround or way to optamize this code?

```
<apex:page controller="MyController" contentType="text/html" readonly="false">
    <head>
        <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
            function FileSize() {
                alert('sdfsdfsd');
                var fileInput = $('#idFileUpload');
                var fileName = fileInput.get(0).files[0].name;
                $("[id$='hdnDocName']").val(fileName);
                if(fileInput.get(0).files.length)
                {
                    var fileSize = fileInput.get(0).files[0].size; // in bytes
                    if(fileSize>100000)
                    {
                        alert('file size is more than 100KB');
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {                       
                        alert('file size is less than 100KB');
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Please select the file to upload');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
        <apex:form id="upload-form">
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <br/>
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!accountID != '' && accountName != ''}">
                <apex:inputHidden id="hdnDocName" value="{!filename}"/>
                <h2>Account Name: <label>{!accountName}</label></h2>
                <br/><br/>
                Please select image (max 100KB):
                <apex:inputFile value="{!doc.body}" filename="{!doc.name}" id="idFileUpload" accept="image/*" fileSize="{!fileSize}"/>
                <br/><br/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Upload" onClick="if (FileSize() === false) { return false; }" action="{!SaveMyFile}"/>   
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!accountID == ''}">
                No valid account selected
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:form>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class:

```
public Pagereference SaveMyFile()
{
    if (fileSize == 0)
    {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Invalid file: Please upload either GIF, JPG, JPEG or PNG file'));
        return null;
    }
    if (fileSize > 100000)
    {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Invalid file: File size exceeds 100KB'));
        return null;
    }
    filename = doc.Name;
    if (filename != null)
    {
        if (filename.toLowerCase().endsWith('.jpeg'))
        {
            doc.Type = 'jpeg';
            doc.ContentType = 'image/jpeg';
        }
        else if (filename.toLowerCase().endsWith('.jpg'))
        {
            doc.Type = 'jpg';
            doc.ContentType = 'image/jpg';
        }
        else if (filename.toLowerCase().endsWith('.png'))
        {
            doc.Type = 'png';
            doc.ContentType = 'image/png';
        }
        else if (filename.toLowerCase().endsWith('.gif'))
        {
            doc.Type = 'gif';
            doc.ContentType = 'image/gif';
        }
        else
        {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Invalid file: Please upload either GIF, JPG, JPEG or PNG file'));
            return null;
        }
        doc.AuthorId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        doc.Name = accountName;
        //doc.body = fileImage;
        doc.IsPublic = true;
        Schema.SObjectField upsertField = Document.Name;

        doc.FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        try
        {
            //insert doc;
            Database.upsert(doc, upsertField, false);
            //getCurrentImage(accountID);
        }
        catch (DMLException e)
        {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading file'));
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            doc.body = null; // clears the viewstate
            doc = new Document();
        }       
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'File uploaded successfully'));
    }
    return null;
}

public Document doc
    {
        get 
        {
            if (doc == null)
            {
                doc = new Document();
                doc.Name = accountName;
                doc.description = '';
                doc.keywords = '';
            }
            return doc;
        }
        set;
    }
```

Comment: Try using "oncomplete" attribute instead of action on commandbutton

Comment: Can you post your apex class?

Comment: added class method

Comment: did you check the view state map and see what variables are hold more kb?

Comment: you can enable it from your user settings, check "Show View State in Development Mode" to true

Comment: MyController >> State >> Controllers >> MyController >> doc. Most of it is from this document.

Comment: One of the solutions for view state would be declaring the variables (doc in your case) static or transient. As I dont see the whole class, is the doc declared as static or transient?

Comment: oops!!! sorry i added doc declaration in the code above. what changes do i need to make?

Comment: Can you make the doc static,  public Static Document doc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40561/discussion-between-user569925-and-anurag-a).

Comment: declare variable which holds the uploaded image with the keyword transient

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the variable "doc" static to avoid view state error

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue lies in the line `var fileInput = $('#idFileUpload');`. As you have used `<apex:inputFile` the id attribute will become something like  `j_id0:upload-form:idFileUpload` in the final html.

You have to use jQuery partial selector .

```
var fileInput = $('[id$=idFileUpload]')
```

Or Salesforce $Component method to select the file input field.

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('{!$Component.upload-form.idFileUpload}');
```

Also please make the id `upload-form` to `upload_form`. Many a times javascript fails if there is an hyphen in a id attribute.